# Decrypting Vanitygen Protected Key

Tags: vanitygen

I've used [Vanitygen](https://github.com/samr7/vanitygen) to generate a vanity Bitcoin address. I used the "-e" option to encrypt the private key. What I can't figure out is how to **decrypt** the protected key that was provided after generating the vanity address, nor can I find the encryption method used.

Is there a utility, library or program that I can use to decrypt the protected key in order to access the private key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buried in the bitcointalk.org forums I found this answer.

Use the keyconv binary file that is included, with the protected/encrypted key as the only  argument:

```
keyconv [Protected Key Here]
```

This will spit out the unencrypted private key. It isn't documented anywhere other than this forum post:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=25804.msg2107686;topicseen#msg2107686

Comment: Lol I reviewed keyconv code but was serching for an flag to decrypt and didn't find it :D. Anyway accept your own answer to help other users.

Comment: that fails with a [`keyconv: util.c:330: vg_set_privkey: Assertion \`EC_KEY_check_key(pkey)' failed.`](https://github.com/samr7/vanitygen/issues/35) for me and others, I had to use [elichai's fork](https://github.com/elichai/vanitygen) which requires a `-d` flag for decryption

Answer (score 1):

I have found a couple of implementations that should help you to decipher the protKey:

- https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=36195.msg1701229#msg1701229 [PHP]
- https://gist.github.com/ianpurton/1139867 [JS]

Also seems that http://insight.gotdns.org/~samr7/pkprotect.html had some more info, but it is down now, maybe Google Cache o Archive.org can help here.

I have not tested anything so don't blame me it they does not work :D

But it seems that it is a format that is not widely used and there is no easy way to decrypt the private key.

Comment: Thanks for the response. These look like potential resolutions within existing applications so they could be helpful. I did find an answer in the bitcointalk.org forums that gave a confirmed resolution (see my self-response).

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/ianpurton/1139867 [JS]
Any idea how to run it.

But try
https://github.com/exploitagency/vanitygen-plus

Windows
keyconv.exe -C BTC -d protected-key
Linux
./keyconv -C BTC -d protected-key